# Buttonclick and postback issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

Below is a code wherein I want to display a message if there is a postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.Write("Hidden value :" + HiddenField1.Value);
    }
}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HiddenField1.Value = "test";
}
```

The issue is I get the message on clicking the button twice, that is clearly because `Page_Load` happens before `btn_Click`. Can anyone suggest me a way wherein I can get the message to be displayed in `if (Page.IsPostBack)` on page postback?

Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you're running into a page life cycle issue. Page_Load happens before any postback events.

If you're just doing Response.Write to the resposne stream, you could move this code to the overriden PreRender event on the page.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.Write("Hidden value :" + HiddenField1.Value);
    }
}
```